# Second script does not recognize variables of first script when first script runs second script method

Tags: python, class, kivy, python-import

I have this script `MainGUI.py` that calls a method from another script `Main2.py`. The `MainGUI.py` script is linked with a `.kv` file named `gui.kv`, in which a method `submitbutton()` is called. This is a function defined in `Main2.py` that will eventually encounter the line `sm.current = "main"`, which is something I have defined in my mother file `MainGUI.py`, in which sm is a `ScreenManager` class and "main" is the name of a `Screen` class I defined in my `gui.kv` file. When the function executes, I'd like the ScreenManager `sm` to go to the "main" Screen. Somehow though, I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'sm' is not defined
```

So I'm presuming I did something wrong in linking variables in between the files but I can't find what. Here's the (relevant pieces of) code:

**MainGUI.py**

```
# importing functionality
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from Logini.Main.Main2 import LoginWindow
from Logini.Main.Main2 import RegisterWindow

# defining screenmanager and screens
class sm(ScreenManager):
    pass
class LoginWindow(LoginWindow):
    pass
class RegisterWindow(RegisterWindow):
    pass
class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass
class PreferencesWindow(Screen):
    pass

# linking .py with .kv
kv = Builder.load_file('gui.kv')

# creating application class that returns variable kv
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return (kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**Main2.py**

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from GUI.MainGUI import sm

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submitbutton(self):
        username = self.username.text
        password = self.password.text
        with open("users.txt", 'r') as ff:
            for i in ff:
                usernamee, passwordd = i.split(';')
                print(usernamee, passwordd)
                print(username, password)
                if username == usernamee and password == passwordd.strip():
                    sm.current = "main"
```

**gui.kv**

```
sm:
    LoginWindow:
    MainWindow:
    PreferencesWindow:
    RegisterWindow:

<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"
    username: username
    password: password

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.3,"y":0.375}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            text: "Submit"
            font_size: 30
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
            root.submitbutton()
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 1, .3, .4, .85
```

Some help would be great! I've already tried importing `sm` in `Main2.py` by using `from GUI.MainGUI import sm` but that only introduces more errors.

EDIT: My folder structure is as follows, with project the root folder: project/GUI/MainGUI.py, gui.kv **and** project/Logini/Main/Main2.py. Calling classes works so I'm assuming no errors follow from importing the classes.

Comment: show your folder structure..

Comment: @adirabargil I've added the folder structure as an 'EDIT' at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from project.GUI.MainGUI import sm
```

Comment: That in turn yields another error:

`Error: cannot import name 'LoginWindow' from 'Logini.Main.Main2' (C:\Users\timda\PycharmProjects\group-31\project\Logini\Main\Main2.py)`

So somehow my `MainGUI.py` script then can not import the `LoginWindow` class from `Main2.py`, which it could when I did not have that line present.